# nginx ingress controller not reading configmap

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes

I have a nginx ingress controller on aks which I configured using [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic). I also wanted to configure the nginx to allow underscores in the header so I wrote down the following configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
   enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
metadata:
   name: nginx-configuration
```

Note that I am using default namespace for nginx. However applying the configmap nothing seem to be happening. I see no events.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
Name:         nginx-configuration
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"enable-underscores-in-headers":"true"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"nginx-configura...

Data
====
enable-underscores-in-headers:
----
true
Events:  <none>
```

Answer (score 7):

Solution was to correctly name the configmap, firstly I did `kubectl describe deploy nginx-ingress-controller` which contained the configmap this deployment is looking for. In my case it was something like this `--configmap=default/nginx-ingress-controller`. I changed name of my configmap to `nginx-ingress-controller`. As soon I did that controller picked up the data from my configmap and changed the configuration inside my nginx pod.

Answer (score 5):

The nginx ingress controller deployment refer to a ConfigMap which can be checked by describing the deployment.

```
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
```

You need to edit that configMap and add that parameter rather than creating new one.

```
kubectl edit cm nginx-configuration -n namespacename
```

Comment: there isn't really no other configmap other than one I created and `ingress-controller-leader-nginx`

Comment: provide the output of kubectl get all -n nginxingresscontrollnamespace

Comment: output of that commands only shows pods, rs, & services nothing about configmap.

Comment: yes
`pod/nginx-ingress-controller-7fbf64f9bd-7jvj5        1/1     Running   0          16h`
`pod/nginx-ingress-controller-7fbf64f9bd-l4s66        1/1     Running   0          16h`
`pod/nginx-ingress-default-backend-7c6cd67dbb-x6fh8   1/1     Running   0      `    14d

Comment: Can you describe the deployment kubectl describe deploy nginx-ingress-controller and add the output in the question

Comment: thank you for the hint, I think I found the solution.